# Nexus 5 Random Static on Screen

Tags: nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 phone that randomly switches to a static display. At that point I just need to power it off and back on again and it usually works. It will randomly go back to the static screen after some usage, but it's totally random, sometimes it goes hours without doing that.

Is there anything that maybe loosened up with time? The phone has been very well cared for, no falls or visible damage and has also been kept in a pocket.

What could be the problem? Is it likely to be a motherboard issue or something simpler?

[image]

Comment: Assuming the phone isn't completely freezing, e.g. you can still getting calls, sms etc... , this could be malware probably. Check your app list for suspicious apps that you didn't install

Comment: I'd start with a fresh ROM - either Lineage or Ubport's Ubuntu Touch. Of the fault continues then it would appear to be hardware related.

Comment: Similar issue on a cheap Orbo ZX-2926D that's several years old, I'm pretty sure it's a hardware issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a hardware issue as I reset the phone to factory settings and it still does it randomly as before.

Comment: If factory reset hasn't fixed it, then it's almost certainly a hardware issue. Being a Nexus device you can easily flash the stock (current / upgraded) ROM to be 100 % sure (just to rule out something isn't wrong with ROM)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same, it starts happening more. I have upgraded my LineageOS but no luck. So it could be indeed a hardware issue